# Azure App Service Antiforgery Error with SSL

Tags: c#, azure, blazor, azure-web-app-service

I have a .Net 7 Blazor WASM app I am trying to deploy to an Azure App Service with a custom domain. When the app is deployed I get the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The antiforgery system has the configuration value AntiforgeryOptions.Cookie.SecurePolicy = Always, but the current request is not an SSL request.
```

My app service is configured to use HTTPS only. Also, I have a managed SSL cert installed on the service.

I have added the Antiforgery like so:

Startup.cs

```
 services.AddAntiforgery(options =>
 {
     options.HeaderName = "X-XSRF-TOKEN";
     options.Cookie.Name = "__someCookieName";
     options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
     options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
 });
```

In my blazor app I have the server serving up the index instead of using a index.razor

_Host.cshtml

```
<script src="antiForgeryToken.js" ></script>
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <UserSecretsId>{GUID}</UserSecretsId>
    <DockerDefaultTargetOS>Linux</DockerDefaultTargetOS>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>    
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Identity" Version="1.9.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets" Version="4.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Server" Version="7.0.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos" Version="3.35.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="7.0.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" PrivateAssets="All" Version="7.0.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets" Version="1.19.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="OpenIddict.Abstractions" Version="4.7.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="OpenIddict.AspNetCore" Version="4.7.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="OpenIddict.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="4.7.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="OpenIddict.Quartz" Version="4.7.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Quartz.Extensions.Hosting" Version="3.7.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" Version="6.32.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Yarp.ReverseProxy" Version="2.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Client\Client.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Shared\Shared.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Please share your `.csproj` file.

Comment: I can see the Antiforgery package has been deprecated, there is a possibility that certain packages might not be installed, leading to SSL certificate issues that you are currently encountering.[Image](https://i.imgur.com/elyRdo2.png)

Comment: @Harshitha I added the csproj